# deploying java war to heroku ,pom.xml error

Tags: java, maven, deployment, heroku, maven-plugin

i want to deploy java war to heroku..and i mentioned the dependencies like below in my pom.xml

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>com.cim.Server.TomcatServer</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>       
        </build>
```

and i have ran

```
mvn package
```

and the i ran

```
D:\HUV\sri>java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.cim.Server.TomcatServer
```

but i got error even though i have the class in the path above..**where am doing wrong??please help**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cim/Server/Tomca
Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cim.Server.TomcatServer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.cim.Server.TomcatServer.  Program will exit.
```

**webapp.bat**

```
@REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Copyright 2001-2004 The Apache Software Foundation.
@REM
@REM Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
@REM you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
@REM You may obtain a copy of the License at
@REM
@REM      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
@REM
@REM Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
@REM distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
@REM WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
@REM See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
@REM limitations under the License.
@REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM

@echo off

set ERROR_CODE=0

:init
@REM Decide how to startup depending on the version of windows

@REM -- Win98ME
if NOT "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto Win9xArg

@REM set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" @setlocal

@REM -- 4NT shell
if "%eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NTArgs

@REM -- Regular WinNT shell
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*
goto WinNTGetScriptDir

@REM The 4NT Shell from jp software
:4NTArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%$
goto WinNTGetScriptDir

:Win9xArg
@REM Slurp the command line arguments.  This loop allows for an unlimited number
@REM of arguments (up to the command line limit, anyway).
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:Win9xApp
if %1a==a goto Win9xGetScriptDir
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto Win9xApp

:Win9xGetScriptDir
set SAVEDIR=%CD%
%0\
cd %0\..\.. 
set BASEDIR=%CD%
cd %SAVEDIR%
set SAVE_DIR=
goto repoSetup

:WinNTGetScriptDir
set BASEDIR=%~dp0\..

:repoSetup


if "%JAVACMD%"=="" set JAVACMD=java

if "%REPO%"=="" set REPO=%BASEDIR%\repo

set CLASSPATH="%BASEDIR%"\etc;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\7.0.27\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-logging-juli\7.0.27\tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\7.0.27\tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\7.0.27\tomcat-jasper-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-servlet-api\7.0.27\tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\7.0.27\tomcat-juli-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-el-api\7.0.27\tomcat-el-api-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\3.7\ecj-3.7.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-api\7.0.27\tomcat-api-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util\7.0.27\tomcat-util-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper-el\7.0.27\tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jsp-api\7.0.27\tomcat-jsp-api-7.0.27.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-context\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-core\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-asm\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\springframework\spring-web\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar;"%REPO%"\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar;"%REPO%"\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.10\slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar;"%REPO%"\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.5.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar;"%REPO%"\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.5.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar;"%REPO%"\log4j\log4j\1.2.15\log4j-1.2.15.jar;"%REPO%"\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;"%REPO%"\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;"%REPO%"\com\cim\controllers\1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT\controllers-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
set EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS=
goto endInit

@REM Reaching here means variables are defined and arguments have been captured
:endInit

%JAVACMD% %JAVA_OPTS% %EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS% -classpath %CLASSPATH_PREFIX%;%CLASSPATH% -Dapp.name="webapp" -Dapp.repo="%REPO%" -Dbasedir="%BASEDIR%" com.cim.Server.TomcatServer %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
goto end

:error
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" @endlocal
set ERROR_CODE=1

:end
@REM set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto endNT

@REM For old DOS remove the set variables from ENV - we assume they were not set
@REM before we started - at least we don't leave any baggage around
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
goto postExec

:endNT
@endlocal

:postExec

if "%FORCE_EXIT_ON_ERROR%" == "on" (
  if %ERROR_CODE% NEQ 0 exit %ERROR_CODE%
)

exit /B %ERROR_CODE%
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the appassembler pluging.  Make sure you have `src/main/java/com/cim/Server/TomcatServer.java` and that the package and class name are correct.

Comment: Yes sir..evry thing is correct...please help

Comment: Sir..what other things i can check sir??

Comment: How about you switch to using the copy-dependencies plugin instead of the appassembler plugin since there is less that can go wrong.  Check out this example: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java

Comment: Also, do you have a `target/classes/com/cim/Server/TomcatServer.class` file after running `mvn package`?

Comment: Yes sir..i have the class in the same path

Comment: Sir...still am getting the class not found error D:\HUV\UVisitors>java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.cim.Server.Tomc
atServer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cim/Server/Tomcat
Server Could not find the main class: com.cim.Server.TomcatServer.  Program will exit.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to Windows case insensitivity in some way.  Make sure your case is consistent in package, directory, file, and class names.

Comment: Sir..but when am doing >mvn compile..iam getting error like package org.hibernate does not exist and org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist

Comment: Ah, well if you can't compile the project then you aren't going to be able to run it.  :)

Maybe you should post a separate question about your compile problems.

Comment: How do you know we're all Sirs here? :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem.

After head banging for 2 days, I drilled down to the error in my `pom`.
It has nothing to do with the `<build>` section.

My problem was that the metadata in pom.xml had an extra `<packaging>war</packaging>` tag.

I modified the metadata to

```
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.my.apps</groupId>
        <artifactId>DummyHerokuApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Dummy name</name>
        <description>Dummy war</description>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

and everything is running smoothly.

I hope this helps you guys.

If you run into this problem again, try to rebuild your `pom.xml` based on what has been provided on heroku devcenter and then add dependencies or whatever incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `pom.xml` file you use `appasssembler-maven-plugin` which generates script for running java appliction. Try to use it. [Example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-program.html)
Something like:

```
Compile: 
mvn package appassembler:assemble

Run:
target/appassembler/bin/app.bat
```

Comment: 'D:\HUV\UVisitors>sh target/bin/webapp.bat
target/bin/webapp.bat: line 1: @REM: command not found
target/bin/webapp.bat: line 2: @REM: command not found
target/bin/webapp.bat: line 3: @REM: command not found
target/bin/webapp.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
target/bin/webapp.bat: line 4: `@REM Licensed under the Apache License, Version
2.0 (the "License");''

Comment: got error sir..one more thing..there is no..appassembler folder generated..i have got ''D:\HUV\UVisitors>sh target/bin/webapp.bat' this one only

Comment: Can you post here `webapp.bat` you got?

Comment: Remove all lines which starts with @REM

Comment: But i found class not found error when am running "D:\HUV\sri>java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.cim.Server.TomcatServer"."D:\HUV\UVisitors\target\controllers-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\cim\Server.TomcatServer.class" please check the classpath

Comment: Look at `CLASSPATH` variable in webapp.bat. This how classpath should look like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10542/discussion-between-user1160126-and-nikita-beloglazov)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/index.html), which does all this work for you automatically. All you need to do is to configure which artifact you want to run and how to run it there:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <name>my-test-app</name>
      <artifacts>
        <artifact>com.example:example-app:jar::${project.version}</artifact>
      </artifacts>
      <procfile>web: java -Xmx256m -jar ./example-app.jar \${PORT}</procfile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That's all you need to configure in `pom.xml`.